# Best WPF control to display a dynamic editable list of strings

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listbox

I am looking for the proper WPF control(s) to display a list of strings subject to the following constraints:

1. The user can edit the single item
2. There may be some "empty" items
3. The code must have access to the list content before and after the editing

Maybe a ListBox or a ListView. Despite spending many hours searching for documentation and examples I am not sure yet if and how to make the list items editable.
I am a novice... sigh

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Another control you could look into using could be a data grid. Each item can be edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid) which is an editable Gridview.

You should create a class to bind DataGrid like as shown

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; } = stirng.empty;
}
```

Then create control in XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgList" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Databases" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>`
```

Then you can write binding

```
string aa = "aa,xx,cc,vv,bbb,hh,gg,rr,tt,yy,uu,ooo";// add your list from DB
dgList.ItemsSource = aa.Split(',').Select(x => new MyItem() { Item = x });
```